# Using Quest powershell cmdlets to change profile info of users in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

Trying to loop through an OU in active directory and then change the HomeDirectory and HomeDrive under profile for all users in said OU.  The only problem I have is when I use the environment variable %USERNAME% in the path of the HomeDirectory it doesn't map correctly.  It will map to the homes folder, but not to the %USERNAME%.  How do I get it to map down to the %USERNAME% folder?  Am I using the wrong variable?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here's my powershell code below:

```
    #Add Snapin for Get-QADuser
    Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

    #Set OU variable
    set-variable -name OU -value "domain.local/Test"

    #Get members of OU then set HomeDirectory and HomeDrive of each user in OU
    get-qaduser -searchroot $OU | set-QADUser -HomeDirectory '\\server\homes\%USERNAME%' -HomeDrive 'H:'
```

Comment: did you try ~ for home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the SamAccountName of each incoming user account

```
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $OU | Foreach-Object{
    Set-QADUser -Identity $_ -HomeDirectory "\\server\homes\$($_.SamAccountName)" -HomeDrive 'H:'
}
```

Comment: I tried Shay's suggestion above and now I get the following prompt:`cmdlet Set-QADUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Identity:`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
"\\server\homes\$env:USERNAME"
```

Note that it is double quotes as well and not single.

Comment: This will map all user's home directory to the same path - the current user that runs the script.

Comment: @ShayLevy - I only answered the direct question.